# Google Form scheduling

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, schedule

I want to develop a google form for scheduling. I would need to limit times available in a drop down based on already scheduled times. I.e.

Barbara is available at 4 and 6 but not 5
Diane is available at 4 but not 5 and 6
Charles is not available 4 5 or 6

So the drop down would only offer 4 and 6 as options. Once submitted the submitter is automatically scheduled to Barbara or Diane based on other criteria like the submitter's last name.

Dates would also become unavailable.

Data collected by the form is biographical in nature so just using google calendar is not enough.

Comment: What do you mean by "develop a google form"? Will you do this programatically?